# 'Swap OS disk' option is missing

Tags: azure

Today two of our Azure servers corrupted after Windows updates. One (DC02) came back up, the other (AP01) went into a boot loop.

We made a copy of the disk, created a new VM, attached the disk and ran a chkdsk. After the entire day, it found errors and fixed them. Now we just need to attach the repaired disk to the original server.

Following the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-recovery-disks-portal-windows, there is no option for "Swap OS Disk". Only the below: [image: Azure]

How can we attach this disk to a VM as an OS disk?

Comment: Is the VM stopped when you're trying to swap the Disk?

Comment: @ConnorDickson It is indeed. We checked on 3 servers and no option for it. I guess it needs to be a managed disk for it to work. Oddly enough, Azure sent us a message saying they have repaired an issue on the server, and now it boots. We didn't even tell the.